# This version of Compose Multiplatform doesn't support Kotlin 1.8.20

Tags: kotlin, compose-multiplatform

in Compose MultiPlatform when I want to `ReBuild` the project I get this error

**This version of Compose Multiplatform doesn't support Kotlin 1.8.20. Please see**
https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/blob/master/VERSIONING.md#kotlin-compatibility
**to know the latest supported version of Kotlin.**

and here is my `build.gradle`:

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.version
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.3.1"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.4.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.dataframe") version "0.10.0"
}

group = "io.visualizer"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        jvmToolchain(11)
        withJava()
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.4.0")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.0.0")
                implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.2.0")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:dataframe:0.10.0")
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "TickVisualizer"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

my `Kotlin` version is `1.8.20` and my `Compose` version is `1.3.1`.
I can simply upgrade the `Compose` version but in that case I can't run the main function!

so the question is how can I downgrade Kotlin version?